# Magento 2.3.3 Generate New Shippment Then Show Blank White Page

Tags: shipment, magento2.3.3

After Upgrade from Magento 2.3.3 then, we save a new shipment then show a white blank page. This blank page comes when we add Tracking Information. When we check the shipment generated successfully.

[image]

Comment: Can you please press CTRL + U in keyboard and check is there any error in your view source page?

Comment: Hello @KishanSavaliya i check with CTRL + U then show all source code but No any error found .

Comment: Can you please open your **app/bootstrap.php** file and uncomment this line there **ini_set('display_errors', 1);** and then refresh your page and check your view source code. @ChiragGondaliya

Comment: Try this but  same result

Comment: Hello, @KishanSavaliya This blank page comes when we add Tracking Information.

Comment: Can you please check which mode you have in your magento using this command ? **php bin/magento deploy:mode:show** ?

Comment: developer mode is enabled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100729/discussion-between-kishan-savaliya-and-chirag-gondaliya).

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug in Magento 2.3.3, 2.3.4 and 2.3.5. Try overriding \vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\templates\email\shipment\track.phtml

Replace this code:

```
<a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getTrackingUrl()->getUrl($_item)) ?>" target="_blank"> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getNumber()) ?> </a>
```

With this one:

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getNumber()) ?>
```

It worked for me.

The solution: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25221

Answer (score 0):

it must have an error.

> First, Access to **file app/bootstrap.php** -> delete the comment of
>   row **ini_set('display_errors', 1);** Then run **bin/magento
>   deploy:mode:set developer** to show error.